# Don't send invites to attendees

Tags: android, android-calendar

I'm utilizing the [`CalendarContract`](http://docs.huihoo.com/android/4.2/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) provider like I should do and everything is working fine (even on android 2.3). Only I was wondering if the following is possible:

When I create a new event and add several attendees, all those attendees get an e-mail invitation like I expect them to.
Now when I update this same event's start date, all of these attendees receive another e-mail that the event is modified. Which is okay.
But I would like the user to specify if the modification should send a notification to all of the attendees, like google calandar does:

[image: google calendar]

is this possible at all, and so; maybe some pointers

Comment: did you figure this out?